# Exclude endpoints when using 'useGlobalGuards' on NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I just started using the `useGlobalGuards` method on my main.ts file:

```typescript
[...]
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({
    transform: true,
  }))
  app.useGlobalGuards(new AuthGuard)
[...]
```

And therefore, all endpoints are using my **AuthGuard**, which throws a 401 error if there's not a valid auth token on the request header... Before this, I was using `@UseGuards(AuthGuard)` on each class, so if I wanted to make a public api (like user creation), I just needed to remove this decorator.

Is it possible to use the `useGlobalGuards` and still have only a few public apis that don't require the auth token? (same question for the `useGlobalPipes` method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a common use case described in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#enable-authentication-globally).

Essentially, you need to create some sort of metadata for the endpoints that will be allowed to use publicly using `@SetMetadata()` or a custom decorator and read that metadata in the guard. If the metadata exists, it should be considered a public route and authentication should be skipped.